# Gradle is generating debuggable APKs on release mode

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following code on my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
        juridico {
            applicationId "br.com.eit.appprovaconcursos"
        }
        enem {
            applicationId "com.ioasys.appprova"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        defaultConfig {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            testCoverageEnabled true
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

To generate de release APK I use the following command:

`./gradlew assembleEnemRelease`

When uploading the generated APK (`app-enem-release.apk`) on the Google Play I got the following error:

**You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.**

I was able to generated a non-debuggable APK by hard coding on android Manifest `android:debuggable="false"`. But the build config still acting like a debuggable build, as you can see in the generate Build.config (I double check and this build config is from the release folder, also I am not receiving any data on Crashlytics, and I disable it from Debug builds).

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.ioasys.appprova";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "enem";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 20135;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "3.0.1";
}
```

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: @Guiherme Torres Castro : Can you please try replacing your gradle file with this http://ideone.com/c376gt

Comment: I am giving the link because I am too not sure of answer but in this way I solved my problem.

Comment: @dex Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it didn't worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out this weird result comes from `testCoverageEnabled true`.

If your release build enabled test coverage, it generates coverage reports then your APK becomes debuggable APK.

Set `testCoverageEnabled` to `false` solve the problem, and it also make sense to not generating coverage reports on release build.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you!

Comment: it would be better if You will report it to Google

Answer (score 3):

As workaround I set debuggable to true in the defaultConfig and in release I override the configuration and set debuggable to false.

Comment: not sure it is a good idea to set `debuggable true` into release mode. It does not seem right